# Count record with two criteria in unbound textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, exception, ucanaccess, data-access

i have fields named "Date of Payment" and "Type of Application". i have also unbound textbox with a name "txtCount". i want to display in "txtCount" the total count of records if "Date of Payment" = year 2022 AND "Type of Application" = "New Transaction". The year 2022 is in another table field name "Calendar Year" and the year 2022 is in text159 using:  `=DLookUp("CalendarYear","tblControlNumber","ControlID")`
this is my current formula in my unbound textbox and i am getting error.
`=Sum(IIf([Type of Application]="New Transaction" And Year([Date of Payment])=[Text159.Value],1,0))`

can anyone help pls, thank you

i want to get Number of New transaction in year 2022 only. and if i update my calendar year 2023, i can also get the number of new transactions in year 2023.

Answer (score 0):

The DLookup() is not complete - WHERE CONDITION needs parameter.

`=DLookUp("CalendarYear","tblControlNumber","ControlID=" & [somefield or textbox])`

Answer (score 0):

As June7 pointed out Text159 isn't set up properly. In this example the equivalent txtYear just has 2022 typed in.  Assuming:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    SomeTableID     |   DateofPayment    | TypeofApplication  |    CalendarYear    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 |         11/24/2022 | New Transaction    |               2022 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 |         10/24/2022 | New Transaction    |               2022 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 |          1/22/2021 | Old Transaction    |               2021 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 |          2/23/2021 | Old Transaction    |               2021 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
txtCount=DCount("SomeTableID","SomeTable","Year(DateofPayment) = " & [txtYear])

txtCountJustRecord= =IIf([TypeofApplication]="New Transaction",1,0)
```

Your issue is most likely that  the IIf() function is referring to just the selected record of the form's RecordSource.  Instead use something like txtCount

[image]

[image]

Comment: txtCountJustRecord= =IIf([TypeofApplication]="New Transaction",1,0) 
is it possible to add another criteria here to call if the date of payment is year 2022 for example?

Comment: Please remember txtCountJustRecord only counts the selected record, but in both statements you can elaborate the restriction in JustRecord replace the 1 with another iff  like iif(DateofPayment = 2022,1,0) and in txtCount after TxtYear append " AND TypeofApplication = 'New Transaction' "

Comment: =DCount("[Type of Application]","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159])+1

This is my Control Sourse on Unbound text box. it count all transaction with the date that specified in Text159.  Now i cant append the Type of Application  = New Transaction. It get error.
=DCount("[Type of Application]","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159]) and ([Type of Application] = "New Transaction") +1 this expression get value 0. Plssss help

Comment: DCount("[Type of Application]","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159]) & " AND ([Type of Application] = 'New Transaction' ") +1     -note the  change in string delimiter around New Transaction and the & before " AND and the " before) +1   -I suggest always setting up a debug.print mywholestring while concatenating strings.  Then check the immediate window to make sure your final string is what it is supposed to be.  Finally,  I suggest using applicationtypeID next time as doing this greatly lowers the programming error rate

Comment: DCount("[Type of Application]","tblMainDBASE","Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159]) & " AND ([Type of Application] = 'New Transaction' ") +1

I put this expression to unbound textbox.  It got error. The expression you entered has too many closing parenthesis

Comment: =DCount("[Type of Application]", "tblMainDBASE", "Year([Date of Payment]) = " & [Text159] & " AND [Type of Application] = 'New Transaction'") +1